# Errors not being recorded to php error log

Tags: php, error-handling

No matter what I do I cannot get php to log errors to a log file.

All the error parameters are set as follows (taken from phpinfo read out):

```
display_errors =    On
error_append_string = no value  
error_log = C:\inetpub\logs\php-error.log   
error_prepend_string =  no value
error_reporting = 22519 
html_errors = On
ignore_repeated_errors = Off    
track_errors = On
xmlrpc_error_number = 0 
xmlrpc_errors = Off
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Jay,

Do you have access to php.ini or PHP Selector (in cPanel)?

Make sure to set error_reporting as E_ALL. Maybe your current settings only shows critical errors and the config I sent before will help you seeing all the errors printed at error.log file.

You also can use the following code at the page you want to generate reports:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If you have any doubt else, tell me here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have been:

1. The specified location for the error-log could not be written to by php. I have specified a new location for the log file and it now works.
2. In terms of screen display of errors I had display_errors set to "On" in the php.ini file and even though phpinfo showed display_errors as being on, it appears they weren't. Changing "On" to "1" in the ini file seems to have done the trick.